# How to trouble shoot - post data to script with CURL

Tags: php, post, curl

I need to post some data to a script on my server.  I'm using curl with and verbose error reporting.  Does anyone have any idea why this is not working please?

Thanks,

Posting script

```
function makePost($postvars, $count) {

$url = 'http://servername.something.org/php/callback-f.php';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

The script which is posted to contains this line:

```
<?php log_error("success",ERROR_LOG_TO_STDERR); ?>
```

My post vars a string which look like this:

```
surname=smth&address1=No+Value&this=that
```

The result i get back is this:

```
Connected to myserver.org port 80
> POST /php/callback-f.php HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.org
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 1510
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: https://myserver/php/callback-f.php
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 16 Nov 2011 16:21:23 GMT
< Server: lighttpd/1.4.28
* Connection #0 to host left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Looks like your test script is only accessible via https but you're posting via http.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer.  Unfortunately that doesn't work.  I get the following error:

Comment: hmmm, problem now is this : SSL: certificate subject name 'Common Name (eg, YOUR name)' does not match target host name 'myservername.org'

Comment: 51 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 52 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 53 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 54 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
 55 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 56 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 57 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 58 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

Ok, I see the issue is this 301 redirect - Thanks for the help!

All that remains now is this: * Violate RFC 2616/10.3.2 and switch from POST to GET

Curl switches to get when redirect. Is there anyway to stop this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting back a 301 error. Your attempted url is `http://servername.something.org` and the 301 is saying the page is to be found at `https://myserver` (note https protocol).

301 errors also are not supposed to redirect on POST without user assent.